# phpmyadmin choose field to display missing in relation view

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, mamp

I am using phpmyadmin 4.0.5. I want to show column value instead of its id while adding a row in a table where that column acts as foreign key.

Now as per https://serverfault.com/questions/365997/how-to-enable-displaying-choose-column-to-display-in-phpmyadmin , I have added

```
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['nrollin'];
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['coaching_field'];
```

in config.inc.php but I see no "choose field to display" option in relation view of coaching_field table. "nrollin" is my database.

Can anyone please tell me what is the possible mistake I am making?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These settings you try are not correct. First, you must install the phpMyAdmin configuration storage (http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage), then you'll be able to go on Structure of this table, click Relation view and "Choose column to display". Afterwards, you'll be able to see either a foreign key dropdown or link, when adding a row.

Answer (score 1):

enable `table_info` in config.inc.php file

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
```